# Get input type 'char' in matlab functions

Tags: matlab

I want to call a matlab function which accepts char inputs. But, I don't want to use 'apostrophy' to define is as a char.

It would look like this while calling

for example :

```
function [] = name(ea,dc) 

%%  Here ea and dc to be char inputs. ( I do not want to use 'ea' and 'dc')
```

So, somehow, my function has to recognize this input as a char input. So, How do it identifies it.

Can you help me ?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  If you don't encapsulate the variables in `''` symbols, MATLAB will interpret that as a variable.  If the two inputs you are using as input into `name` don't exist in your workspace or wherever you're calling the function before you call this `name` function, MATLAB will spit out an error.  Please give a better example of how `name` is to be called and **why** you want to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ischar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html).  This checks to see if an input into this function is a character array, and reports `true` if it is and `false` otherwise.  Take note that a single character is also a character array... it's simply a 1 x 1 array.

Therefore, you could do something like this in your code:

```
function check(ip1, ip2)
    if ischar(ip1)
    %//... Do something if ip1 is a char
    else
    %//... Do something else if ip1 is not a char
    end

    if ischar(ip2)
    %//... Do something if ip2 is a char
    else
    %//... Do something else if ip2 is not a char
    end
```

Comment: @user3476378 - No problem.  Let me know if this works... and if it does, I wouldn't mind if you accepted my answer.  Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work for the following situation :   **  While calling the function, if I enter inputs without ' apostrophy', then It doesn't work. That was my main question, I want to enter inputs without apostrophy and somehow, the function identifies it as a character input and do my task.

Comment: @user3476378 - That doesn't make any sense.  If you don't encapsulate the variables in `''` symbols, MATLAB will interpret that as a variable.  If the two inputs you are using as input into `name` don't exist in your workspace or wherever you're calling the function before you call this `name` function, MATLAB will spit out an error.  Please give a better example of how `name` is to be called and **why** you want to achieve your goal.